# How to cast a referenced entity in HQL to its sub-class

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hql

Suppose there are following entities (JPA annotations are not written):

```
class Questionnaire {
    ...
}

class Policy {
    private Questionnaire questionnaire;
    ...
}

class LifeQuestionnaire extends Questionnaire {
    private String someField;
}

class LifePolicy extends Policy {  
    ...
}
```

Well as it seems a Policy references a Questionnaire, but a `LifePolicy` references a `LifeQuestionnaire` (this restriction is always true).

Is there any way I can write a query like this:

```
from LifePolicy lplc
where ((LifeQuestionnaire) lplc.questionnaire).someField = :fieldValue
```

As you can see, I want to have some kind of casting in the HQL query, because `someField` is only available in `LifeQuestionnaire`.

Comment: sounds to me that your  mapping is not correct given your constraint. I am guessing that your LifePolicy object should define a LifeQuestionnaire property with an overidding of the mapping of the Questionnaire of Policy or something alike.

Comment: AFAIR, you can do it without any cast, just as if the field was in Questionnaire..

Comment: Consider `Questionnaire` and `Policy` inheritance is mapped using Joined Subclasses.

Comment: @JBNizet well the field is not in the Questionnaire, and I can't move it to that class, because I use joined-subclass strategy.

Comment: What I'm saying is that, even if the field is in the subclass, you can use it in a HQL query as if it was in the base class.

Comment: @asermax well as you can see I want to return instances of `LifePolicy` by filtering on `LifeQuestionnaire` properties. By the way I have simplified my questionnaire, the main query has more restrictions, some are on `LifePolicy`, some are on other classes referenced from `LifePolicy`.

Comment: @JBNizet as far as I know, if I reference a property which is not defined in the mapped class, hibernate won't allow using it in a query (an exception is thrown while parsing the query). By the way I will test it one more time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem and have found a solution that worked for me. Its not very nice but it works. Try using a 'Cross' join. e.g.

```
select (specify what you want to fetch) 
from LifePolicy as lp, LifeQuestionnaire as lqn 
inner join lqn.questionnaire as q 
where lqn.id = lp.id 
and q.someField = :fielfValue
```

sources:

https://www.jumpingbean.co.za/blogs/mark/hibernate 
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-from

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments:

Even if the field is in the subclass, you can use it in a HQL query as if it was in the base class. I tested it and it is working.

```
from LifePolicy lplc
where lplc.questionnaire.someFieldInSubclass = :fieldValue
```